# How to clear the values from an input field when a new input is added to another input field using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, angularjs, django

My project is working on Django/Python and AngularJS. I've encountered an issue like whenever the user input a new value to the input field, the value he selected in the previous input drop-down list need to be cleared off (Both of the input fields are doing the same job, like if the user cant find the value in the drop-down, he manually adds the value, ie. Both of the input fields are using the same ng-model) An explicit way(either one of the value need to be added to the DB). Can someone suggest me a solution? Currently whatever I select in the dropdown list is been copied over to the input field. Am very much new to AngularJS, please forgive if it is a stupid question. The following is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><b>MASKS</b></span>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-change="get_masks()"
                                    ng-model="final_data.mask" ng-options="m as m for m in masklist" required ng-cloak>

                            </select> &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><b>MASKS*</b></span>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-change="get_masks()" ng-model="final_data.mask"
                                   type="input" ng-cloak>&nbsp;
                        </div>

                    </td>
```

Comment: It is because you are using same ng-model for input and select option.

Comment: You did everything right. It gets cleared as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

It is because I used same ng-model for input and select option, just realized. Thanks to Jigs